# Porosity in class sampling in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Hello dear**
Probably the topic I chose for this discussion may not be very appropriate, but let's get to the problem

In PHP I have a class called **`DB`** and in this **`class`** I write database relationships to **connect to the database**:

```php
class DB {
    private static $_dbConnect = null,
    $dbUser = DB_USER,
    $dbPass = DB_PASS,
    $dbName = DB_NAME,
    $dbTable = null;
    function __construct($dbTable) {
        self::$dbTable = $dbTable;
        if (!isset(self::$_dbConnect) || self::$_dbConnect == null) {
            try {
                self::$_dbConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".self::$dbName,self::$dbUser,self::$dbPass);
                $isResult = self::$_dbConnect->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM ".self::$dbName." LIKE '${dbTable}'");
                if ($isResult->rowCount() == 0) {
                    $isQuery = "";
                    if ($dbTable == DB_TABLES['user']) {
                        $isQuery = ""; //write user table query
                    } else if ($dbTable == DB_TABLES['admin']) {
                        $isQuery = ""; //write admin table query
                    }
                    self::$_dbConnect->prepare($isQuery);
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                throw $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    private function ifString($strings=[],$sep='&') {}
    private function stringSep($strings=[]) {}
    public function existValue($strings=[]) {}
    public function insertTB($data=[],$ifArray=[]) {}
    public function getDataTB($ifArray=[]) {}
    public function updateTB($data=[],$ifArray) {}
    public function deleteTB($ifArray) {}
    public function getAllRecords($ifArray=[]) {}
    function __destruct() {
        if (isset(self::$_dbConnect) || self::$_dbConnect != null) {
            self::$_dbConnect = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is because I defined the database connection in **`__construct`**, I get into trouble when I run two instances of this `class` at the same time:

```php
$DB['user'] = new DB(DB_TABLES['user']);
$DB['admin'] = new DB(DB_TABLES['admin']);
```

The problem is that now when I try to use **`$DB['user']`**, things are done on **`$DB['admin']`**

Have a solution friends?

**Note: If I ask the question a little bad I apologize because I am Farsi**

Comment: Why don't you just create _one_ instance of PDO and then just pass queries to it? I don't see the point of creating multiple instances? (and you're currently overwriting the old one with the new one, since you're using `static`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` declaration for `_dbConnect`. static means the variable is defined **once** regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

```
private $_dbConnect = null,
```

If `$_dbConnect` is not static, references to `self::$_dbConnect` should be replaced with `$this->$_dbConnect`.

Comment: Don't forget to replace all occurrences of `self::$` with `$this->` as well.

Comment: The problem was solved though thanks to user **Magnus Eriksson**